# What is an entry in a dictionary?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, definition, dictionaries

I see the marketing on selling dictionaries "350,000 entries and meanings", I searched in the dictionary and I get

An entry is:

[image]

The description is too general, what is an item in a dictionary?

What else is written other than words? Only words

What else is printed other than words? Are there is a variety of charts, drawings, and images?

Comment: charts, drawings and images illustrate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "entry" in a dictionary is a **headword** (the word that gets looked up), plus its definition and any ancillary information that pertains to that word, such as an etymology, any usage notes, example sentences, pronunciation guides, inflected forms of the word and any illustrations. It is everything that is presented as belonging to that headword.

Comment: So to practice, entry is a word only if it has ancillary information e.g. diagrams, meaning, etc. If the word doesn't have ancillary information is it not an entry? Like the [index/list](https://i.imgur.com/Rn8Cw3f.png) words?

Comment: No, that's not right. Some dictionaries are primitive and have only definitions. Each word with its definition can be called an entry.

Comment: If only has the word but without definition is still called entry? Or always entry is accompanied by something else?

Comment: If you have just a list of words, then you can say each word is an "entry" in that list. It's just not an entry in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

An entry in a dictionary is a word that the dictionary gives a definition for.

You could say "How many words are in this dictionary?", but that would be ambiguous. If a dictionary says, for example, "hat: (n) A covering for the head", that's clearly one "entry". But is it one "word", that is, one word that is defined? Or is it 6 words: the word being defined plus the 5 words used to define it?

Some dictionaries include things besides words with definitions, like lists of abbreviations, etc. These might also be counted as "entries".

Comment: So entry is not only the word itself that's being defined but is also can be the explanation like the meaning, charts, drawings, etc that's right?.

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona Yes.